# Create Python Virtual Environment on Windows10 without Some Admin Rights

Tags: python, windows, python-venv

I just installed Python3.10.1 from the Windows10 App Store.
Showing help is OK

```
 python -m venv --help
```

actually creating a venv is not

```
python -m venv venv
# -> Error 1260: Windows cannot open this program because it has been prevented by a software restriction policy
```

I guess it is those exe files generated on Windows when creating a venv (btw --symlinks does not help).

Is there any way to **create** a virtual environment without some admin/AppLocker rights?

More insights:
The command actually *does* create the following structure

```
venv
│   pyvenv.cfg
│
├───Include
├───Lib
│   └───site-packages
└───Scripts
        python.exe
        pythonw.exe
```

But *site-packages* is empty, independent of whether we choose *--system-site-packages* or not.

Comment: Using `--without-pip` helps, so this seems to be related to [Create venv with pip fails when target dir is under userappdata using Microsoft Store python](https://bugs.python.org/issue45337), which was supposed to be solved with Python 3.9.

Comment: And [venv python reports wrong sys.executable in a subprocess on Windows](https://bugs.python.org/issue38905) mentions [PEP 582](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0582/)

Comment: I opened https://bugs.python.org/issue46056

Comment: I know it's an old question, but is python installed on a path with any space? If so, you might have bitten by the bug that I just [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71039131) The behavior is different from what I experienced, likely because you're using the App Store version. Sorry if this isn't related at all.

Comment: No spaces in path. The problem is caused by MS AppLocker or Defender policies.